# Call back function in modal of bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, callback, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im a little bit confuse about firing a call back function in javascript modal of bootstrap3. In normal `jquery.post` you can do it like,

```
$.post('path', { something: something }, function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
});
```

But in bootstrap 3 modal I fires the modal through script and I do it like this base on how I understand the explanation in their website.

```
$('selector').modal('show', function() { 
  //here comes the problem, I have a button in the modal in the html, my code
  //if the button was clicked inside this modal is..

  $('#myButton').on('click', function() { 
     console.log("this is a try");
  });
});
```

But sad to say if I click the button, nothing is happening, nothing was logged in the console. How do I call a callback function in a modal of bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, the events are now namespaced, so the `show` event for the modal would be `show.bs.modal`...

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('modal show');
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/90952

Comment: This doesn't work for me on version 3.3.1, can this be improved?

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work for me first time but I believe that is due to it being a click on a button to activate this however now I have split it out into click and event it now works.

Comment: This event triggers before the modal has completely loaded. See rborodinov's answer.

Answer (score 18):

[@Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676392/call-back-function-in-modal-of-bootstrap3/19683032#19683032) is right, you can use the `show.bs.modal` event like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('modal show');
});
```

The official documentation says:

> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

Please note that this event is fired "quite soon" and you may need to use `shown.bs.modal` instead.

Documentation about this event:

> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

This impacts [@Keith yeoh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676392/call-back-function-in-modal-of-bootstrap3/26487279#26487279) answer and you should **avoid timeouts** when possible.

Source:
[Official Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Comment: `show.bs.modal` didn't work for me at all. Using `shown.bs.modal` was the fix for me. Thanks!

Comment: `shown` is called when the modal finishes opening, `show` is called when it begins opening. You should figure out why it did not work, as this is unexpected behavior and they are not aliases of each other.

Comment: There is this small N in show.bs and showN.bs. Thanks for the documentation tip! ;)

Answer (score 11):

Just a little to add for the 1st answer, it is because when the callback is triggered the DOM inside the modal is not completely loaded yet, perhaps should do a little hack here to holdback the action after callback for a while. Hope it helps!

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // something here
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: timeout save my life!

Comment: The DOM inside the modal isn't loaded when `show.bs.modal` is triggered, but the DOM *is* ready when `shown.bs.modal` is triggered. `show.bs.modal` is triggered *before* the modal is shown, `shown.bs.modal` is triggered *after*.

Answer (score 10):

I think better will be, to use "shown.bs.modal" it is fiered when modal is allready loaded. [Bootstrap modal events](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('modal is allready shown');
});
```

Comment: Exactly! show is when modal starts to show, shown when done

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    ...modal callback here.
});
```