# Bootstrap Modal and Jquery Address ajax redirection timing issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-address

I have a web app which is using the ajax for loading the main content of the page. I am using jquery address to handle the navigation with ajax. I have a form which shows up in the modal and on successful submission, I want to redirect the user to a new page. Here's the code:

```
//called when form is submitted
$('#modal-form').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        method: method
    }).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
        // Check for 401 unauthorized
        if (xhr.status === 401) window.location = '/auth/login/';
    }).done(function (data, status, xhr) {

        $('#modal-form').modal('hide');  //Hide the modal
        redirect(xhr);   //Redirect to a new page
    });
});
```

Now, the problem is before the modal is completely hidden the page redirect happens causing it to be black and inaccessible. I tried moving the redirect call into the complete function too, but doesn't seem to work. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676392/call-back-function-in-modal-of-bootstrap3

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use modal callback to run redirect after modal is finished:

```
$('#modal-form').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    redirect(xhr);
});
```

Comment: Presumably you can chain, `$('#modal-form').modal('hide').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {...})`, or would it be the other way round?

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work, redirect is called before the modal completely closes causing the screen to be inaccessible.

Comment: I was missreading on the docs, it should be hidden which occurs after the hide effect, see my edit.