# How could I write a code that executed after modal-body is shown to user

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap-modal(**I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2**) and I want to write a code that will be executed after modal-body is loaded and shown user( but before close it) So here is my modal:

```
<div id="input-output-match" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
        <h3 id="input-output-match-header"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id='match-body'></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <form>
            <button class="btn" id='modalCancel' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id='save' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ok</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside modal-body, I'm adding some div elements dynamically inside of my javascript codes. Now I want some part of my code will be executed after the modal is shown the user as I said before. Is there any way to do that? Something like callback function?

Comment: Probably after you do `$("MODAL_ID").modal('show')`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I tried it, actually I write a console.log('test'); inside that function but even it is not written on the console

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676392/call-back-function-in-modal-of-bootstrap3

Comment: or could you prepare a jsfiddle or something, so we can see more of the code!?

Comment: @zwlayer, How do you load your modal body? ajax call?

Comment: @MatthiasPosh see my question and look what did I write about my bs version

Comment: You mean bs **2** and you mean `on('shown.bs.modal')` doesn't work, right?

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't use the instructions from [bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)?  It's pretty simple:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

> shown - This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for css transitions to complete).

Comment: `$("#input-output-match").on('shown', function () {
  console.log('you should see this in the console');
})` and it does not shown in the console thats why I'm asking

Comment: @Shehary Actually I dont know it, this is my first js trial and I've limited knowledge. Do you know how could I check it/

Comment: @zwlayer This will give you complete idea how to use B.S Modal event function http://jsfiddle.net/a87kh0jv/1/

Comment: @zwlayer jQuery DOM ready, find detail here https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Shehary this was exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div id="input-output-match" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
                    <h3 id="input-output-match-header"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id='match_body'>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form>
                        <button class="btn" id='modalCancel' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id='save' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ok</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>





   <script type="text/javascript">
   demo('match_body');
  function demo(){
  alert('function is runing');
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     <div id="input-output-match" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
                    <h3 id="input-output-match-header"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id='match_body'>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form>
                        <button class="btn" id='modalCancel' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id='save' data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ok</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>





   <script type="text/javascript">
   demo('match_body');
  function demo(){
  alert('function is runing');
    }
   </script>
```

I have modified this code for run js script to run on start (load time) onload only used for some elements body,img,iframe, run this script you will get a alert masager

Comment: could you show me how to trigger this function in my code?